# Is there any way to use one component page in vue.js while restricting the other components?

Tags: vue.js

I am building the web-app, which includes the authentication page like login.vue and register.vue components, also I'm using the drawer.vue page as the core component, i.e I'm using the drawer.vue component in the whole project or in all other components.

The problem here is that I do not want to use drawer.vue component in login.vue and register.vue components.

I have tried this to restrict the register.vue component by doing "v-if="$route.name !== 'register'" in the app.vue file.i.e.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <core-toolbar v-if="$route.name !== 'register'" />
    <core-drawer v-if="$route.name !== 'register'" />
    <core-view />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

The problem here is that I am unable to restrict the login.vue component, I'm only be able to restrict the register component, does any one have better solution for this?

Comment: When app loads, by default load `core-drawer` & `core-toolbar` with false and when user `login` or `register` into the app, store the user value in localstorage and make the flag `true`. Hope this works!

Comment: Is there a route to the login component? If so, why are you not adding it to the `v-if` condition? You can use this syntax: `['register', 'login'].includes($route.name)`

Comment: ya, there is route for login and register both, sorry but i didnt get you, can you please elaborate, about what you are saying @RashadSaleh